# Trapped in freebsd-update fetch with strange End display

Tags: freebsd

FreeBSD noob here. When I run `freebsd-update fetch` on a fresh install of FreeBSD 12.0, it ends with, well, **End**, without taking me back to a prompt. How do I exit this screen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're in a pager, such as `less` or `more`.  Try pressing the `q` key (a mnemonic for **Quit**).

Comment: Thanks! I kept typing :q like I would in Linux; never occurred to me to try a solitary q.

Comment: In the absence of a pager setting it defaults to more or less, however, setting to less requires the -e option to quit on end.

`PAGER="less -e" freebsd-update fetch`

PAGER can be set to “cat” when a non-interactive pager is desired

Answer (score 1):

the freebsd-update script uses PAGER from env, irritates me, so I do the following

in ~/.cshrc

```
setenv PAGER less
```

change to

```
setenv PAGER
```

and 
in ~/.profile

```
PAGER=less
export PAGER
```

change to

```
PAGER=
export PAGER
```

if PAGER doesn't exist, the freebsd-update script sets it itself, so you need to leave the export with no value. it will obviously affect all scripts using PAGER too, but regardless, I'd rather use less intentionally.